# Disturbing bootstrap4 button horizontal alignment due to adding extra text to upper section?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have created the grid systems layout in bootstrap to showcase my 3 courses 
in that i have shown course image on top in middle course  title and at bottom course enroll button, in that whenever am going to insert multi-line title for particular text the all courses button will not be in same horizontal height means their alignment get disturbed

You can refer to the "HIGHLIGHTED COURSES" section in http://demo.proserindustries.com/

Comment: how do you want these to look when you introduce a multi-line text label?

Comment: so after that how you want to see your card, provide image of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these 2 properties to your CSS to get all the buttons aligned

```
.mb-5 .btn-secondary { bottom: -12%; position: absolute; left: -webkit-calc(50% - 52.5px); left: -moz-calc(50% - 52.5px); left: calc(50% - 52.5px); }
.mb-5, .my-5 { margin-bottom: 7rem!important; }
```

**Explanation**:

1. width of the button is 105px, which is why we had to move it 52.5px so that the button becomes centered
2. You may want to play around with the `margin-bottom` as per your exact requirements - best practice is to ask your content team to have headings within a fixed number of characters